# Hide froala on blur events

Tags: angular, froala

I am using forala with following setting:

```
initOnClick: true,
```

works perfectly fine, but is there a possibility to achieve the "counterpart" I want to hide the editor on blur.

I did not find anything in the documentation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anybody has the same issue here is the solution:

```
  events: {
blur: function() {
  this.toolbar.hide()
},
focus: function() {
  this.toolbar.show()
}
```